# Where to find an active bootstrap repository server?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, repository

I am trying to install Arch Linux. I have already extracted and downloaded the bootstrap image. After that, the instructions say:

> Select a repository server by editing
>   `/tmp/root.x86_64/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`.

I used nano to open the file that contained links to the repository servers. Here are the links to the server.

```
http://mirror.umd.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
http://mirror.vtti.vt.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
http://mirrors.xmission.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
http://mirror.yellowfiber.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
http://f.archlinuxvn.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
http://mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

I'm unable to access the server. Are there any alternative links, or will I have to resort to a different method of installing Arch?

Comment: "None of the files work" is not an error message: what is the actual problem? And why don't you just install from the live medium?

Comment: I edited my question and added pictures to give you a better idea. I initially attempted an instillation by UEFI, but it wouldn't boot.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text, paste the *actual text*. And read the wiki page, you are trying to download the repo: nowhere does it say to do that.

Comment: jasonwryan, perhaps you can show me how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are following the instructions to [bootstrap an archlinux image from an existing linux environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux#From_a_host_running_another_Linux_distribution).

After downloading the bootstrap image:

```
curl -O http://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/iso/2015.10.01/archlinux-bootstrap-2015.10.01-x86_64.tar.gz
```

and extracting it:

```
tar xzvf archlinux-bootstrap-2015.10.01-x86_64.tar.gz
```

you have to edit the mirror list:

```
vi root.x86_64/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

In this list all servers are commented out, you have to uncomment one or several servers based on your localization.

```
##
## Arch Linux repository mirrorlist
## Generated on 2015-09-23
##

## Worldwide
#Server = http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Australia
#Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.rackcentral.com.au/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.swin.edu.au/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.uberglobalmirror.com/$repo/os/$arch

## Austria
#Server = http://mirror.digitalnova.at/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.easyname.at/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror1.htu.tugraz.at/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Bangladesh
#Server = http://mirrors.ispros.com.bd/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Belarus
#Server = http://ftp.byfly.by/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Belgium
#Server = http://archlinux.cu.be/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mirror.kangaroot.net/$repo/os/$arch

## Brazil
#Server = http://archlinux-br.mirror.host1plus.com/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.c3sl.ufpr.br/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://www.las.ic.unicamp.br/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://linorg.usp.br/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://pet.inf.ufsc.br/mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.pop-es.rnp.br/$repo/os/$arch

## Bulgaria
#Server = http://mirrors.netix.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.telepoint.bg/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.uni-plovdiv.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirrors.uni-plovdiv.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Canada
#Server = http://archlinux.dropswitch.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.its.dal.ca/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mirror.rafal.ca/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mirror.vexxhost.com/$repo/os/$arch

## Chile
#Server = http://mirror.archlinux.cl/$repo/os/$arch

## China
#Server = http://mirrors.163.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.hust.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.hustunique.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.opencas.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://run.hit.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.zju.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Colombia
#Server = http://mirror.edatel.net.co/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://www.laqee.unal.edu.co/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Croatia
#Server = http://archlinux.iskon.hr/$repo/os/$arch

## Czech Republic
#Server = http://archlinux.mirror.dkm.cz/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://gluttony.sin.cvut.cz/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.nic.cz/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.vpsfree.cz/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Denmark
#Server = http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.one.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Ecuador
#Server = http://mirror.cedia.org.ec/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.espoch.edu.ec/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.uta.edu.ec/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Estonia
#Server = http://ftp.eenet.ee/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## France
#Server = http://archlinux.aubrac-medical.fr/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.archlinux.ikoula.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.vi-di.fr/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mir.art-software.fr/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.bitrain.co/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://fooo.biz/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://fooo.biz/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.lastmikoi.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.bitjungle.info/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirror.bitjungle.info/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mailtunnel.eu/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://www.mailtunnel.eu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mir.archlinux.fr/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://arch.nimukaito.net/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mirrors.ovh.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mirror.pkern.at/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://archlinux.mirror.pkern.at/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.polymorf.fr/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://arch.static.lu/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://arch.static.lu/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://arch.tamcore.eu/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.tyborek.pl/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.u-strasbg.fr/linux/distributions/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://arch.yourlabs.org/$repo/os/$arch

## Germany
#Server = http://mirror.23media.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.limun.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://archlinux.limun.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://artfiles.org/archlinux.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror5.bastelfreak.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.euserv.net/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.fau.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://ftp.fau.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.flipez.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.fluxent.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirror.fluxent.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.fs.cx/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirror.fs.cx/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.gnomus.de/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://arch.packages.gnp-tec.net/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://www.gutscheindrache.com/mirror/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.hactar.bz/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.hawo.stw.uni-erlangen.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.honkgong.info/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://archlinux.honkgong.info/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.archlinux.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.js-webcoding.de/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirror.js-webcoding.de/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://k42.ch/mirror/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://k42.ch/mirror/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.metalgamer.eu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.michael-eckert.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.my-universe.com/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://archlinux.my-universe.com/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.n-ix.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.netcologne.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.niyawe.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.pseudoform.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirror.pseudoform.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://linux.rz.rub.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.selfnet.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.spline.inf.fu-berlin.de/mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.tuxdroid.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.uni-hannover.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.uni-kl.de/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.united-gameserver.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Greece
#Server = http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://foss.aueb.gr/mirrors/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://foss.aueb.gr/mirrors/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.myaegean.gr/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.otenet.gr/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Hungary
#Server = http://ftp.mfa.kfki.hu/pub/mirrors/ftp.archlinux.org/$repo/os/$arch

## Iceland
#Server = http://mirror.system.is/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirror.system.is/arch/$repo/os/$arch

## India
#Server = http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Indonesia
#Server = http://mirror.kavalinux.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.poliwangi.ac.id/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://suro.ubaya.ac.id/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Iran
#Server = http://repo.sadjad.ac.ir/arch/$repo/os/$arch

## Ireland
#Server = http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ftp.archlinux.org/$repo/os/$arch

## Israel
#Server = http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Italy
#Server = http://archlinux.openlabto.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.beccacervello.it/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.prometeus.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Japan
#Server = http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/Linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/ArchLinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Kazakhstan
#Server = http://mirror.neolabs.kz/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Latvia
#Server = http://archlinux.koyanet.lv/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Lithuania
#Server = http://archlinux.akmc.lt/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.atviras.lt/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Luxembourg
#Server = http://archlinux.mirror.root.lu/$repo/os/$arch

## Macedonia
#Server = http://arch.softver.org.mk/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.t-home.mk/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Netherlands
#Server = http://arch.apt-get.eu/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.i3d.net/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirror.i3d.net/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://www.imegumii.nl/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## New Caledonia
#Server = http://mirror.lagoon.nc/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.nautile.nc/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## New Zealand
#Server = http://mirror.xnet.co.nz/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Norway
#Server = http://mirror.archlinux.no/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.uib.no/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.neuf.no/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Philippines
#Server = http://mirror.rise.ph/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Poland
#Server = http://arch.midov.pl/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://piotrkosoft.net/pub/mirrors/ftp.archlinux.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.vectranet.pl/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Portugal
#Server = http://archlinux.dcc.fc.up.pt/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.rnl.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Romania
#Server = http://mirror.archlinux.ro/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mirrors.linux.ro/$repo/os/$arch

## Russia
#Server = http://mirror.rol.ru/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.yandex.ru/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Serbia
#Server = http://mirror.pmf.kg.ac.rs/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Singapore
#Server = http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Slovakia
#Server = http://mirror.lnx.sk/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://tux.rainside.sk/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## South Africa
#Server = http://ftp.wa.co.za/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## South Korea
#Server = http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/ArchLinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.premi.st/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Spain
#Server = http://osl.ugr.es/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://sunsite.rediris.es/mirror/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Sweden
#Server = http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.df.lth.se/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.dynamict.se/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.myrveln.se/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://ftp.myrveln.se/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.portlane.com/pub/os/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Switzerland
#Server = http://archlinux.puzzle.ch/$repo/os/$arch

## Taiwan
#Server = http://archlinux.cs.nctu.edu.tw/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://shadow.ind.ntou.edu.tw/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.tku.edu.tw/Linux/ArchLinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Turkey
#Server = http://ftp.linux.org.tr/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Ukraine
#Server = http://archlinux.bln-ua.net/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.nix.org.ua/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## United Kingdom
#Server = http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.cinosure.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.manchester.m247.com/arch-linux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.archlinux.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://arch.serverspace.co.uk/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.mirrors.uk2.net/$repo/os/$arch

## United States
#Server = http://mirrors.abscission.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.acm.wpi.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.aggregate.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.surlyjake.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://repo.atlantic.net/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://cosmos.cites.illinois.edu/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.cs.pitt.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.es.its.nyu.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror1.gaw.solutions/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror2.gaw.solutions/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror3.gaw.solutions/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.gigenet.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.grig.io/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.ancl.hawaii.edu/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.htnshost.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://arch.mirrors.ionfish.org/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://kwk.pw/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://kwk.pw/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.liquidweb.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://arch.localmsp.org/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://arch.localmsp.org/arch/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://lug.mtu.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://lug.mtu.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.metrocast.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.nexcess.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://archlinux.pallissard.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.redsox.cc/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.rit.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.rutgers.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.umd.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.vtti.vt.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirrors.xmission.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.yellowfiber.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Vietnam
#Server = http://f.archlinuxvn.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

The list of servers you provide in your question is not the right one. Start again and double check every step.